# FlexBox Align-items não funciona

Tags: aplicação-web, flexbox, css

Estou com um problema, não entendi muito bem o conceito de **Align-items** em **flexbox**, não sei porque não está funcionando, segue código:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center">
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 250px; width: 250px">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid animi architecto beatae
            debitis dignissimos dolore et id magnam molestias nisi perferendis perspiciatis,
            qui quis quo quod sed vero voluptas voluptatum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara está tudo funcionando direitinho. O "problema" é que seu *container* pai não tem altura, ai não alinha...

Veja o seu código, apenas colocando altura no pai *container* e uma borda pra vc visualizar melhor.

**OBS:** Como o *container* é uma `div` elá já tem 100% de largura. Por isso inicialmente o filho já ficava no centro do pai.

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; height: 500px; border:1px solid red;">
 <div style="background-color: red; height: 250px; width: 250px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid animi architecto beatae
   debitis dignissimos dolore et id magnam molestias nisi perferendis perspiciatis,
   qui quis quo quod sed vero voluptas voluptatum.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tô achando que ele queria alinhar o texto na div vermelha. :D

Comment: Então por padrão o elementos tem que estar setados na altura e largura correto? Para poder trabalhar com display: flex.

Comment: @RafaelBalmant não necessariamente como vc viu. No seu código o elemento já estava centralizado na horizontal pelo fato da DIV ter por padrão a largura de 100% da tela. Ai o justfy-contente funcionou como esperado. Já para vc alinha na vertical é preciso que tenha alguma altura definida em algum lugar, pois como vc vai alinha no centro de 0. Mesmo que a altura do pai tenha 100%, ou 100VH ou coisa do tipo é importante que tenha algum valor... E o alinhamento com flex é sempre o alinhamento do filho em relação ao pai. Pai com Flex, ai vc alinha o Filho com as propriedades do flex.

Comment: ...continuando @RafaelBalmant  e quando o Pai tem flex o filho tb ganha algumas propriedades para se alinhar individualmente dentro do pai, são as propriedads terminadas em `-self` tipo, aling-self ou justfy-self

Comment: @Sam quando eu bati o olho tb achei que fosse isso rss, mas depois que vi que os estilos estavam no container de "fora" ai me liguei que poderia ser como mencionei na resposta...

Comment: @hugocsl, entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda deu uma ajuda monstra aqui. Valeu mesmo :)

Comment: @RafaelBalmant inclusive, se vc recortar os estilos Flex do container Pai, e colar junto dos estilos Filho, box vermelho, vc vai ver que o texto tb vai alinhar no centro do box. Que bom que ajudei. depois da uma olhada nesse guia https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @RafaelBalmant Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone **`✔`** abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita. Abs